# Model Not Learning with many training data

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

So Im trying to make a colorizer using Convolutional neural network. I searched for some models form the internet for this and I think they work because I have tested them on one image input the gray scale and made the model memorize the image. It doesnt look like exactly the original image but the gray scale becomes colored which I think is atleast OK.

So I tried to feet a lot of data on the model and some epochs around 10 to 30 and  the model outputs black and white image when processed. Im not really sure why this is happening. Please help.

```
from PIL import Image                                                            
import numpy                                                                     
import glob
import os 
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from skimage import io, color
#Neural Network model 
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim

# class lanscapes():


if torch.cuda.is_available():
    device=torch.device("cuda:0")
    print("running on the GPU")
else:
    device=torch.device("cpu")
    print("running on the CPU")

label = 'training'
IMG_SIZE=800
size=5
REBUILD_DATA = True
class landscapes():
    
# imagePath = glob.glob(imageFolderPath + '/*.JPG') 
    

    def make_training_data(self):
        global training_data
        training_data=[]

        for f in tqdm(os.listdir(label)):
            path = os.path.join(label, f)
            img = cv2.imread(path)
            img = cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
            img=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            training_data.append(img)
                        
        training_data=numpy.asarray(training_data)
        f, axarr = plt.subplots(2)
    
        axarr[0].imshow(training_data[0])
        axarr[1].imshow(training_data[1])
        
    def rgb2lab(self,training_data):
        global L
        global ab
        L=np.zeros((size,800,800))
        ab=np.zeros((size,800,800,2))
        for i in tqdm(range(size)):
            L[i]= color.rgb2lab(1.0/255*training_data[i])[:,:,0] #grayscale image
            ab[i] = color.rgb2lab(1.0/255*training_data[i])[:,:,1:]
            ab=ab/128
            # L=L/100
            
        L=torch.Tensor([L]).reshape(size,1,800,800)
        ab=torch.Tensor([ab]).reshape(size,2,800,800)
        return L,ab
    
if REBUILD_DATA:
   td=landscapes()  
   td.make_training_data()
    
# training_data=np.load("training_data.npy",allow_pickle=True)

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1=nn.Conv2d(1,32, 3,stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)) #conv layer with 3 kernel size
        self.conv2=nn.Conv2d(32,32, 3,stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1)) 
        self.conv3=nn.Conv2d(32,64, 3,stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)) 
        self.conv3a=nn.Conv2d(64,64, 3,stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1))
        self.conv4=nn.Conv2d(64,128, 3,stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)) 
        self.conv5=nn.Conv2d(128,128, 3,stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1)) 
        self.conv6=nn.Conv2d(128,256, 3,stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)) 
        self.conv7=nn.Conv2d(256,128, 3,stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)) 
        self.conv8=nn.Conv2d(128,64, 3,stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)) 
        self.conv9=nn.Conv2d(64,32, 3,stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)) 
        self.conv10=nn.Conv2d(32,16, 3,stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)) 
        self.conv11=nn.Conv2d(16,2, 3,stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        self.up=nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2)
       
       
        
    def forward(self,x):
        x=F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x=F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x=F.relu(self.conv3(x))
        x=F.relu(self.conv3a(x))
        x=F.relu(self.conv4(x))
        x=F.relu(self.conv5(x))
        x=F.relu(self.conv6(x))
        x=F.relu(self.conv7(x))
        x=F.relu(self.conv8(x))
        x=self.up(x)
        x=F.relu(self.conv9(x))
        x=self.up(x)
        x=F.relu(self.conv10(x))
        x=torch.tanh(self.conv11(x))
        x=self.up(x)
       
        # x=torch.tanh(self.conv8(x))
        # return torch.tanh(y,dim=1) #output
        return x
# net=Net()
net = Net().to(device)
optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.001)
loss_function=nn.MSELoss()
Lb=np.zeros((1,800,800))

def fwd_pass(X,y,train=False):#checking if youre training 
     
    if train:
        net.zero_grad()
    outputs=net(X)
    loss=loss_function(outputs,y)
    
    if train:
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    return loss

def train():

    EPOCHS=10

    for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
            for i in tqdm(range(size)):
                # Lb=L[i].reshape[1,1,800,800]
                loss=fwd_pass(L[i].view(1,1,800,800).to(device),ab[i].view(1,2,800,800).to(device),train=True)
            print(f"Epoch: {epoch}. Loss: {loss}")

def test():
    X="datasets_298806_1217826_00000000_(2).jpg"
    path=X
   
    path = cv2.imread(path)
    patha=cv2.cvtColor(path, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    path = cv2.resize(patha, (800,800))
    gs= color.rgb2lab(1.0/255*path)[:,:,0] #transform test to input
    abt = color.rgb2lab(1.0/255*path)[:,:,1:]
    # gs/100
    abt=abt/128
    gs=torch.Tensor([gs]).reshape(1,1,800,800)
    abt=torch.Tensor([abt]).reshape(1,2,800,800)
    gs=gs.cuda()
    abt=abt.cuda()
    losst=fwd_pass(gs.to(device),abt.to(device),train=False)
    print(f" Loss: {losst}")
    out=net(gs)
    out=out*128
   
    canvas=np.zeros((800,800,3))
    gs=gs.reshape(800,800)
    gs=gs.cpu().detach().numpy()
    # out=out.cpu().data.numpy()
    canvas[:,:,0] = gs
    out=out.cpu().detach().numpy()
    out=out.reshape(800,800,2)
    canvas[:,:,1:] = out
    canvas=color.lab2rgb(canvas)
    
    f, axarr = plt.subplots(2)
    axarr[0].imshow(canvas)
    # axarr[1].imshow(X)
    axarr[1].imshow(patha)
    plt.imsave('model.jpg', canvas)
    plt.imsave('orig.jpg', path)

        
       
                 

L,ab=td.rgb2lab(training_data)
L=L.cuda()
ab=ab.cuda()
train()
test()
# output=net(L)

# f, axarr = plt.subplots(2)
# axarr[0].imshow(L[1])
# canvas=np.zeros((800,800,3))
# # axarr[1].imshow(ab[1])
# canvas[:,:,0] = L[1].reshape(800,800)
# canvas[:,:,1:] = ab[1]
# canvas=color.lab2rgb(canvas)
# axarr[1].imshow(canvas)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that you should either use batching, or accumulate gradients, or reduce LR.

Also, I suggest to plot your train loss. If train.loss decreases normally, add validation set and plot val.loss as well. You may need to add BatchNorm, augmentations, reduce image size, tune optimizer...

You can also find some inspiration in [this article](https://blog.slavv.com/37-reasons-why-your-neural-network-is-not-working-4020854bd607) or find a good implementation of an auto-encoder colorization.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply! I also tried batch learning but it did not have any effect :(. Id check that article you sent! Thank you!

May I ask what do you mean by accumulate gradients? Didnt the model do that automatically? Thanks man!

Comment: Gradient accumulation is when you make several forward passes, take sum of losses, and then do optimization step. This is useful when your desired batch size exceeds GPU memory. Good luck!

Comment: One more advice, a bit off-topic. Have a look at PyTorch Lightning framework. It helps to structure code and apply many training tricks with little effort.